# Decorate The Table

Tags: logic

we have r red, g green and b blue balloons. To decorate a single table for the banquet we need exactly three balloons. Three balloons attached to some table shouldn't have the same color. What maximum number t of tables can be decorated if we know number of balloons of each color?

Task is to find the maximum number t of tables, that can be decorated in the required manner.
example-
5 4 3(red ,green, blue)
answer is 4 , with the following balloon sets: "rgg", "gbb", "brr", "rrg", where "r", "g" and "b" represent the red, green and blue balls, respectively.

I am really stuck with this problem. Help!

Comment: Ignoring the color condition and just putting 3 balloons on every table until you run out the maximum is obviously $\lfloor (r + g + b) / 3 \rfloor$. Your 12 baloons fit on 4 tables-example is just this. What you need to do is think about how or if the ratios of the colors might make this maximal number lower when you factor in the color criterion. Imagine how you would go actually practically go about decorating the tables if this was job you had to perform.

Comment: "Three balloons attached to some table shouldn't have the same color" , does this impact the above formula (r+g+b)/3. for example (7 1 1) answer is 2.     (rrg,rrb)